# Xcache install, repo giving old verison

Tags: php, apache, xcache

I'm trying to install xcache onto my server to try and improve site speeds.

I'm following the guide provided here http://www.tecmint.com/install-xcache-to-accelerate-and-optimize-php-performance/

Which the first step is to do the fellow

```
yum install php-xcache xcache-admin
```

However doing this from the shell I get the following error

```
Error: Package: php-xcache-3.0.4-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.32-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
Error: Package: php-xcache-3.0.4-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.32-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20090626
```

Looking from the error it seems that an old version of xcache is trying to be installed (3.0.4). Is there a way to either work around this (such as is it safe to use `--skip-broken`).

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are using remi repository to use PHP 5.4.
Package php-xcache is in epel and in remi repository, so when you specify to install php-xcache, CentOS tries to install from epel repo.

Try this:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install php-xcache xcache-admin
```

If this won't help, try to disable epel by default;

1. Edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` and set `enabled=0` in `[epel]` section
2. run `yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install php-xcache xcache-admin`
3. Restore `enabled=1` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`